# Method not implemented!, "grpc_status":12

Tags: python, grpc

I have created a GRPC service and client. Service is working and hosted on port 5001 but the client is throwing GRPC error as Method not implemented.

**Server**

```
class CalculatorService(Calculator_pb2_grpc.CalculatorServicer):

    def SquareRoot(self, request, context):
        response = Calculator_pb2.Number()
        response.value = Calculator.square_root(request.value)
        return response


server = grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10))

Calculator_pb2_grpc.add_CalculatorServicer_to_server(
    Calculator_pb2_grpc.CalculatorServicer(),
    server)

print('Starting Server on port 5001')

server.add_insecure_port('[::]:5001')
server.start()

print('Server Started')

server.wait_for_termination()
```

**Client**

```
channel = grpc.insecure_channel('localhost:5001')

number = Calculator_pb2.Number(value=16)

response = Calculator_pb2_grpc.CalculatorStub(channel).SquareRoot(number)

print(response.value)
```

**Error**

```
C:\Users\anshul_jain\.virtualenvs\pythonCalc-hTzam63Y\Scripts\python.exe C:/Projects/GRPC/pythonCalc/client.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Projects/GRPC/pythonCalc/client.py", line 8, in <module>
    response = Calculator_pb2_grpc.CalculatorStub(channel).SquareRoot(number)
  File "C:\Users\anshul_jain\.virtualenvs\pythonCalc-hTzam63Y\lib\site-packages\grpc\_channel.py", line 946, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
  File "C:\Users\anshul_jain\.virtualenvs\pythonCalc-hTzam63Y\lib\site-packages\grpc\_channel.py", line 849, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _InactiveRpcError(state)

grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: _InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.UNIMPLEMENTED
    details = "Method not implemented!"
    debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1630568886.349000000","description":"Error received from 
 peer \u00109\u00cc\u008f\u00a8\u0001",
    "file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc",
"file_line":1070,"grpc_message":"Method not implemented!","grpc_status":12}"
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Please include the proto file that you used to generate your client|server stubs.

It's unclear from your code, but `SquareRoot` must appear as a method on the service as well as be implemented by the server. You've shown the latter but not the former.

It may be worth considering a tool such as [gRPCurl](https://github.com/fullstorydev/grpcurl) to test your service.

Also, your implementation of `SquareRoot` appears incorrect. You'll want to use something like `math.sqrt()` to calculate the square root to return (and check for exceptions).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps changing in Server:

```
server.add_insecure_port('[::]:5001')
```

for

```
server.add_insecure_port('localhost:5001')
```